# How to connect to OpenLDAP which created by official helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, kubernetes-helm, openldap

Using Helm 3 installed OpenLDAP:

```
helm install openldap stable/openldap
```

Got this message:

```
NAME: openldap
LAST DEPLOYED: Sun Apr 12 13:54:45 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
OpenLDAP has been installed. You can access the server from within the k8s cluster using:

  openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389


You can access the LDAP adminPassword and configPassword using:

  kubectl get secret --namespace default openldap -o jsonpath="{.data.LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}" | base64 --decode; echo
  kubectl get secret --namespace default openldap -o jsonpath="{.data.LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD}" | base64 --decode; echo


You can access the LDAP service, from within the cluster (or with kubectl port-forward) with a command like (replace password and domain):
  ldapsearch -x -H ldap://openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD


Test server health using Helm test:
  helm test openldap


You can also consider installing the helm chart for phpldapadmin to manage this instance of OpenLDAP, or install Apache Directory Studio, and connect using kubectl port-forward.
```

However I can't use this command to search content on ldap server in the k8s cluster:

```
export LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=[REAL_PASSWORD_GET_ABOVE]
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

Got error

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

---

I also login to the pod to run

```
kubectl exec -it openldap -- /bin/bash
# export LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=[REAL_PASSWORD_GET_ABOVE]
# ldapsearch -x -H ldap://openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
```

The same.

Comment: I tried recreating your problem and ran the ldapsearch command from a pod next to the deployment, from the openldap pod and locally using `kubectl port-forward` and couldn't recreate your problem.  could you try the port-forwarding command `kubectl port-forward <POD_NAME> 3890:389; ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost:3890 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD`? And if that doesn't work, describing your service and add it to your post?

Comment: @Totem Thank you. I did `Kubectl port-forward` then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the notes:

> NOTES:
>   OpenLDAP has been installed. You can access the server from within the k8s cluster using:
>
> `openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389`
>
> You can access the LDAP adminPassword and configPassword using:
>
> `kubectl get secret --namespace default openldap -o jsonpath="{.data.LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}" | base64 --decode; echo`
>    `kubectl get secret --namespace default openldap -o jsonpath="{.data.LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD}" | base64 --decode; echo`
>
> You can access the LDAP service, from within the cluster (or with `kubectl port-forward`) with a command like (replace password and domain):
>    `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://openldap.default.svc.cluster.local:389 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD`
>
> Test server health using Helm test:
>    `helm test openldap`
>
> You can also consider installing the helm chart for phpldapadmin to manage this instance of OpenLDAP, or install Apache Directory Studio, and connect using `kubectl port-forward`.

You can do:

```
$ kubectl port-forward services/openldap 3389:389 
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3389 -> 389
Forwarding from [::1]:3389 -> 389
Handling connection for 3389
```

From another shell, outside the Kubernetes cluster:

```
$ kubectl get secret --namespace default openldap -o jsonpath="{.data.LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD}" | base64 --decode; echo
l3dkQByvzKKboCWQRyyQl96ulnGLScIx
$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost:3389 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w  l3dkQByvzKKboCWQRyyQl96ulnGLScIx
```

Also it was already mentioned in a comment by [@Totem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432893/totem)